# Google's reCAPTCHA - systemjs missing

Tags: angular, typescript, recaptcha

I am trying to implement Google's reCAPTCHA  in Angular following [this tutorial](https://github.com/leewinder/ng2-google-recaptcha)
and I couldn't find  systemjs.config.js in my Angular CLI project. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a "systemjs.config.js" file and load it from index.html, like a regular script

```
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
 <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
```

**(!!! Important you should include** `system.src.js` **before** `systemjs.config.js` **file )**

This is an example for SystemJS.config.js File

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Refer to [this tutorial for more information](https://scotch.io/courses/getting-started-with-angular-2/systemjs)

Comment: (You need to create a "systemjs.config.js" file ) which folder ?

Comment: In where ever you want, But need to load it in the Index.html , The common practice is to create it in the root directory of the project

Comment: after adding in index.html i got this error's  GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js 
systemjs.config.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
    at systemjs.config.js:1

Comment: Do you have the system.src.js in node_modules folder?

Comment: yes , it is available  system.src.js in node_modules folder